# Cómo llamar una imagen desde CSS en mi repositorio de Github?

Tags: css, github

Soy nuevo en esto del Desarrollo Web, y esto haciendo los retos de [Frontend Mentor](https://www.frontendmentor.io/).

Me surgió un problema cuando cree el repositorio, pues desde mi PC puedo ver la imagen que llame desde mi archivo CSS pero cuando lo voy a abrir desde el repositorio ya no llama ninguna imagen.

Me podrían ayudar por fa?

**Repositorio:** https://github.com/cacuitiva/Card_Componet

**Enlace:** https://cacuitiva.github.io/Card_Componet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar tu problema de la imagen, simplemente debes ir a tu archivo css y en tu css modificar lo siguiente:

**ANTERIOR**

```
.img{
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    background: url(images/image-header-desktop.jpg);
    background-blend-mode: overlay;
    background-color: #693183;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**ACTUAL**

```
.img{
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    background: url(../images/image-header-desktop.jpg);
    background-blend-mode: overlay;
    background-color: #693183;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

El problema que te ha pasado es simple, no te has acordado de retroceder hacia atrás, ya que tu carpeta de imágenes se encuentra fuera de la carpeta css y por ello debías retroceder una vez simplemente añadiendo dos puntos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: No hay de que, me alegro de que te sirviera

Answer (score 0):

la ruta sería url(../images/image-header-desktop.jpg)

Esto sería porque si te fijas, en tu estructura, tienes dos carpetas, una de css y una de imagenes, para hacer referencia a la imagen desde el archivo css que esta dentro de la otra carpeta, tienes que ir hacia atras, esto se hace usando los dos puntos ..

Una vez sales de la carpeta css, tendrías que entrar a la carpeta de imagenes:
../images

Y luego hacer referencia al archivo
../images/image-header-desktop.jpg

Como te comento, esto depende de la estructura de carpetas que tengas, si por ejemplo, tuvieses el archivo css y la imagen en una misma carpeta, no te haría falta volver atras.

Espero te haya quedado claro

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la ruta relativa

"background: url(images/image-header-desktop.jpg);"

Estando en el archivo css, deberías primero salir desde directorio y luego entrar a images.

Prueba con "../images/"

Para más información, visita:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037959/css-root-directory